# Failed to update Mysql data using Ajax, how to fix it?

Tags: php

I'm trying to update a row using Ajax, it failed.

Here my code

```
<button onclick="updateAjax(<?php echo $row['id_doc']; ?>,this)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

function updateAjax(id_doc,obj){
$.ajax({

  type: 'get',
  url: 'toIndex.php',
  data: {nama_file:id_doc},

  success:function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    if(data){

      alert("Data berhasil diupdate");

    }else{

        alert("Data gagal diupdate");
    }
  }

}); }
```

On the **toIndex.php** page

```
$nama_file = $_GET['nama_file'];
$update = "UPDATE documents SET status_index = 1 WHERE nama_file='".$nama_file."'";
if($conn->query($update) == TRUE){
   echo json_encode(true);
}else{
   echo json_encode(false);
}
```

the `alert("Data berhasil diupdate")` is **work**, but the mysqli query is failed to update the data.
Any solution?

Comment: Ajax function must be in jquery script. It seems you have written in php.

Comment: `Add dataType = 'JSON'` if you want responce as JSON format

Comment: put your query code in a `try{..}catch{...}` block see what error you get

Comment: Make sure $row['id_doc'] has a value and if non numeric its php tags should be enclose in `''`

Comment: enclose you js script in <script> tag

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/5914775). Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187/5914775). Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send data like this

```
 data: 'nama_file='+nama_file+'&id_doc='+id_doc,
```